# Does having Abuse and Postmaster Emails help to stop being treated as SPAM?

Tags: domains, email

I read on some blog (I don't remember the URL) that having abuse@mydomain.com and postmaster@mydomian.com in addition to main email help to prevent our mails from being categorized as spam. Is it true? Is it worthy to create two additional email accounts. On my hosting, only 5 are allowed. Please suggest.

Comment: You should be able to setup a 'forward' instead and save your mailboxes? Usually the limit on 'forwards' is much higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear so.  After a quick search I turned up a few links that described why it is important to have.

http://www.activewebhosting.com/faq/email-postmaster.html

http://forums.macresource.com/read.php?1,132477,132509

Comment: Just to add, regarding your first link to activewebhosting.com, the bit of info that states, "This [postmaster] is where E-Mail ends up which is addressed to a non-existant account on your domain" - is just how that particular webhost has set things up in this case.

Comment: Although the information is sound, the fact the articles are from around 2006 makes me wonder if Google and other companies still have the same measures because much as changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's (maybe) just wrong text, but having these mailboxes doesn't change classifications of e-mail.
Having postmaster@ is a requirement from RFC-world, having abuse@ is just bon ton (proper) between postmasters.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I've never heard of such requirements with any of my recent web development projects, nor have I even had clients use those exact emails. Even at my company we stick with emails on a real name basis because abuse & postmaster are so generic that they're essentially spam magnets for bots since it's a default term.

If you wanted to play it safe you always could use an alias and forward it to a main account or just delete all email through there. From my experience, even at the server level on Linux, when I setup Dedicated/VPS DNS Servers I've used my primary company email so I'm atop of any issues.