# Why/What is the need for an abuse email account for website domain?

Tags: php, server

My website has email address for me to contact but few have suggested me to have an abuse@yourdomain.com email address.. Please clarify my doubt if someone can.

Comment: In theory, it is required to have the abuse@ e-mail address or they can take your domain name. That does happen. Mine goes to a spam folder because that is all you will get. My registrar sends any complaints via another undisclosed e-mail address because of the private registration. This works. I get valid requests very rarely,only twice in the past bunch of years, and I can act upon them.

Comment: @closetnoc "or they can take your domain name." - Who's "they"?

Comment: Related: [Does having Abuse and Postmaster Emails help to stop being treated as SPAM?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17851/does-having-abuse-and-postmaster-emails-help-to-stop-being-treated-as-spam) and [Should I set up standard email accounts? What are they?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2030/should-i-set-up-standard-email-accounts-what-are-they)

Comment: @w3dk My bad! The postmaster account is the required account. It has been a long time since I have experienced this, it was also part of the security stuff that I did, however, there are/were blacklists that tested the working presence of the e-mail addresses and the validity of whois registration information and would add a domain to their blacklist if found not to be accurate or have the proper e-mail addys. From there the registrar would suspend a domain name until satisfied or after a relatively short period return the domain name into the pool to be registered. I have seen this happen.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you manage your mail and who is operating mail server.

If your e-mail server is hosted by your ISP, web-hosting company or service like Google Apps, you do not have to, they already do that. For example if you buy Google Apps you can set up your own address@example.com, the abuse@example.com will be redirected to administrators from Google, same goes with webhosting company or ISP.

---

If you have your own mail server, you should have abuse@ set up along with @postmaster and others. There is a lot of reasons for this, main reason is there must be a contact person when someone missuses or abuses from your domain and you want to know when this happen, I think nobody will take your domain, but your ISP will disconnect your server and reroute your IP if you will not respond in time.

Nobody is going to take spam or abuse for granted these days and no service provider is going to tolerate, if something bad like spam, viruses or other suspicious activity originates on your server, because they have rented it to you and most likely their name is in the IP whois contact database, usually with abuse@ e-mail.

Comment: If you want to know more, also read https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2142.txt